# How can I disable ARC for an entire group/folder of files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm aware that you can set the compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` to disable Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) for each file in Compile Sources in XCODE but how can I do this for an entire group of files without having to do each file at a time?

The reason I ask is that I've added a large library to my application and I need to set the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag for over 100 files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Goto `Build Phases -> Compile sources` select multiple files holding <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> and press enter then add the value `-fno-objc-arc` It will reflect for all the selected files.

Comment: And how can you sort the files here?

Comment: Note for small-screens: You have to resize the panels (project explorer, property inspector) to see the "Compiler flags" combo on the right of the file entries. To see the popup when pressing enter, i had to leave the mouse over the combo. Finally worked:) +1

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that XCode lets you set this flag for a folder or a group, but you have two reasonable alternatives to setting the flag on individual files:

1. If your library is self-contained, you can create a separate project for it in the same workspace as your application, and disable ARC for that project.
2. If you are OK modifying the source of that library, you can attempt an automated ARC conversion.